# What's the best way to get rich?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I'm going to be getting married soon, and that costs quite a bit, house and tool upgrades are also becoming quite costly.

What method(s) are the best way to make money in a reasonable amount of time? (I don't exactly want to spend months on it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to get money reasonable quick, but they require a bit of investment of your time and money. The first method requires much more of your time than the second one, but you also get much higher profits. These methods work all-year round (I think)

### 1.) Make golden/silver cloth out of flax (or cotton) - Requires Sewing Studio

**Initial investment:**
Sewing Studio: 40,000 G (Sold by Silk Country - no requirements)
Flax Seeds: 260 G (Sold by Silk Country - Ship 150,000 G to Silk Country)
Cotton Seeds: 320 G (Sold by Rose Country - Ship 1,000,000 G total)

ROI: ~ 14 golden linen cloth units sold | ~12 golden cotton cloth units sold

Since you already have the Sewing Studio, all you need to do is plant a ton of flax. After harvest, go into the Sewing Studio and make Linen Thread out of it, using the Spinning Wheel. 1 unit takes 15 in-game minutes to make, so you can just queue up all you got (30 units is the maximum per queue).

When the thread is finished, you need to dye it. Dying takes the longest (both time and effort wise): 6 hours and 50 minutes (in-game) per unit.
If you want it to be finished in some reasonable time, I suggest you make queues of 5.

After the dying process is finished, you just need to make cloth out of it. Making cloth only takes one hour.

Depending on the quality of your cloth, you can sell it for (approximately) these prices:

Linen:

- 1 Star: 3000 G
- 3 Stars: 5000 G
- 5 Stars: 7000 G

Cotton:

- 1 Star: 3600 G
- 3 Stars: 6000 G
- 5 Stars: 8400 G

### 2.) Make Chilli Powder out of Chilli Pepper - Requires Seasoning Shed

**Initial investment:**
Seasoning Shed: 40,000 G (Sold by Wheat Country)
Chili Pepper Seeds: 600 G per unit (Sold by Silk Country - Summer of year 2 OR Conquest the Spice Field)

ROI: ~ 84 Chilli Powder units sold

Again, you need to plant lots of chilli pepper. After harvest, go into the Seasoning Shed and make chilli powder out if your pepper, using the seasoning pot. 1 unit only takes 15, so it's a rather fast process.

You can sell the chilli powder for these (approximate) prices:

- 1 Star: 480 G
- 3 Stars: 800 G
- 5 Stars: 1120 G

Before you sell your stuff, check if a trader wants cloth or spices (you can sell them for a bit more). Also be aware that if you sell too much of a certain category, selling prices will lower for that category at this trader.

Either wait for the next day or sell to another trader.

If you already have your own trading spot, you can just fill it up with cloth/spices and sell everything. Prices won't go lower and you get a notify when you sold everything.

Prices taken from: http://fogu.com

Comment: what's ROI mean?

Comment: @Rapitor - Return of investment.

Comment: I think these prices are for Seedling Mode as my Golden Linen Cloth doesn't sell for *nearly* as much as this.

Comment: @Yuuki - Probably. I currently don't have the time to check, so if you have proper prices, you can edit them in.

Comment: difficulty doesn't change how much things sell for, only how much they cost to buy.

Comment: A couple of points I would add are that you want to prioritize upgrading your tools as this will limit how much you can grow, and you want to fertilize only only one 3x3 plot of a given crop in order make more time available for growing more crops. Make seeds from the produce from that plot and repeat the process until you get 5 star seeds. I'd also emphasis the need to split jobs when using the dyeing pots to make gold/silver linen thread. You can have up to 30 jobs going at once and they all run in parallel.

Comment: I wouldn't advise to make jobs of 30 when dying the thread. 1 unit takes 6 hours an 50 minutes, so to dye 30 units would take roughly 8 days. Better to invest the time and split up the jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I love the pottery shed for making money. I just buy all of the dirt the vendors sell and crank out pottery. It all takes different amounts of time so up to a week later I still have pottery coming out that I can sell.

Answer (score 0):

One way I make money is I go to the  mine, If you visit the mine every day for a while and save up on your gems, you can get loads of (in-game) money.

Another way is if you have a sheep, Llama, camel, Alpaca, bunny, or goat you just need to collect their fur, sometimes sakura country wants clothes so just get the sewing shed and then spin the wool into as much cloth as you can make, then make clothes out of the cloth and make as many outfits as you can. 
Depending on the date, it might not be the time sakura country wants your clothing so just wait.
(I'm In a hard position too, I have all of the materials for the two story house but I don't have furry animals to make clothes, I used to have a sheep, alpaca, camel, and a suffolk sheep.
Plus, I am at pink FP with raeger so I have to get more money for the blue feather.)
Good Luck!